# Storing events via Keycloack

Tags: logging, synchronization, timeout, keycloak

I would like to describe the issue first. In the system we have a client that does not use Keycloak, and they use their own written module to store users. Therefore, a special "synchronizer" block has been created which transfers users from their module to Keycloak (this is actually an extension of Keycloak) - in this case, not Keylcoak manages users but this module.

Now, I need from Keycloak to save events such as: information about login (correct), information about incorrect login, about logout and session tiemout - all this should be available from the Keycloak level. As far as I know Keycloak already reads this data (although I do not have much experience in Keycloak), the only issue is uploading this information to syslog. The only problem is the session timeout, because you will probably have to trigger Keycloak to do it (is this issue mentioned somewhere in the documentation?). The client is using Splunk - the only thing he needs is to feed this Splunk with data - how to do it (I'll be grateful for any guidance, useful links, docs etc.)?

Btw. As I mentioned above, our "synchronizer" block synchronizes users but does not synchronize mail, unfortunately I do not know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Keycloak admin REST api in order to get/find the various admin events in json format:

```
GET /{realm}/admin-events
```

There are several possible filter/parameters (namely a dateFrom/dateTo)
See the doc here:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/12.0/rest-api/index.html#_realms_admin_resource